# Django don't serve static

Tags: python, django, static

why not boot css in some pictures?
my settings.py:

```
ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cd = lambda *a: os.path.join(ROOT, *a)
PROJECT = os.path.basename(ROOT)

MEDIA_ROOT = cd('public/uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
STATIC_ROOT = cd('public/assets')
STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

my template .html:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}themes/css/bootstrappage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Look at your html source and find out what is the final path.  Is it what you think it should be

Comment: source <link href="/assets/themes/css/bootstrappage.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I believe the path of the images called from css file are wrong. The paths in CSS and JS files are not rendered by Django.

Comment: If that is correct path, does it work on the django test server, but not on production server?  If so, its a webserver configuration issue

Answer (score 1):

Once you make sure the paths are correct, you are going to want to use the proper format in your templates, the last format recommended by the Django team is:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
<link href="{% static "themes/css/bootstrappage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Check out the [documentation on static files from djangoproject.com](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for full steps and details.

Comment: OK, then you are also going to want to check out the Django documentation on deploying your status files for production:
[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/